# How can I dynamically edit the fill of a path in an SVG at runtime in Android Kotlin Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, svg, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

I am attempting to display a world map SVG file where I can dynamically edit the fill color of each country. Each country has a path in the SVG with an associated id that is the country's 2 letter code.

The SVG file looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="2754" height="1398">
    <title>World Map</title>
    <style id="style_css_sheet" type="text/css">

...lots of css styles...

        </style>
<path id="us" class="landxx sd" d="..."</path>
<path id="ca" ...>
```

I can manually edit the file and add style for the paths to change the country fill color easily via adding the line `.us {fill: blue}` for example in the style section, but I can only do this manually before my application runs. I cannot figure out how to do this at runtime programmatically. Does anyone know how this can be done in jetpack compose android kotlin for an android app?

My endgoal is to create a dynamically fillable world map for countries and this seemed the most promising option based on my research but if there is a better approach please share.

I have tried several approaches but all have failed.

1. Open the file, and dynamically insert the style edits to fill country's. The file itself changes as expected but the image never refreshes with the new style. I am guessing this is due to the fact the image uses rememberAsyncImagePainter from coil library so it does not think it needs to refresh.

```kotlin
val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
        .components {
            add(SvgDecoder.Factory())
        }
        .build()

Image(
        painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(File(context.filesDir, "worldmap_filled.svg"), imageLoader)
        contentDescription = "World Map",
        modifier = Modifier.sizeIn(maxHeight = 800.dp)
    )
```

Also, this approach seems impressively wasteful to constantly read the file in and rewrite it.

2. I have also tried reading the SVG as a VectorDrawable but that was also having issues. I could not figure out how to display the Drawable object in my app, nor how I could change the style of the country fills.
3. I tried to convert the SVG to a jetpack compose object (via online tools) but the SVG is rather large and the country id's were dropped during conversion so this was fruitless as well.
4. Another idea I have but it seems too hacky is to try and wrap the image in html code and then render the html code.
5. I was thinking maybe I would have to split the SVG from one large SVG to many SVG, one for each path and then layer all these to recreate the world map and then can apply a theme to each SVG individually similar to the solution described here (https://emmav.me/posts/2015-nov-29-dynamic-svg-colours/), but that again seems overkill if it even would work.

I was expecting there to be a fairly simple solution where I can read the SVG to an object, and then dynamically apply style to object. Something similar to the below pseudocode:

```kotlin
val svgObject = readSvg("example.svg")

svgObject.applyStyle(".us, .ca, .fr {fill: blue} ")

Image(svgObject, ...)
```

Comment: I eventually found a solution. First, I read in the SVG file and parse it manually to get each path, and then loop over each path and drawPath() in a Canvas object to create all the paths. I can color each individual path by setting its style as Fill and setting a color.